# ObservableCollections are no longer returned when I update my service reference

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have a Silverlight 5 app. This app has been in development for 18 months. This app calls back to a WCF service. I just had a support request.

Before today, the service would return `ObservableCollection<T>` results. However, now all of the sudden, out-of-the-middle of nowhere, it starts returning `T[]` results after I updated the service reference in the Silverlight app.

My question is, what could have happened that would cause this change? This has caused approximately 70 errors due to type conflicts. Am I overlooking a basic setting?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a service reference to communicate with the service, make sure the Data Type hasn't been changed.  Right click on the service in the Service References folder, select Configure Service Reference..., and look at the Data Type - Collection type:.  If it's System.Array, then this may be your problem.  Change it to ObservableCollection and see if that helps.